# How To Create Custom Line Chart in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, linechart

I just want to line chart in my flutter application like below image.

[image: Below link image is Line chart i want to create of image]

Here is my code but the result output is normal. i am using charts_flutter: ^0.9.0 packages.

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
    import 'package:flutter_screenutil/screenutil.dart';
    
    import 'data/sale_data.dart';
    
    class LineChart extends StatelessWidget {
      // Defining the data
      final data = [
        new SalesData(1, 7),
        new SalesData(2, 19),
        new SalesData(3, 6),
        new SalesData(4, 3),
        new SalesData(5, 10),
        new SalesData(6, 21),
        new SalesData(7, 3),
        new SalesData(8, 10),
        new SalesData(9, 5),
        new SalesData(10, 15),
        new SalesData(11, 8),
        new SalesData(12, 12),
        new SalesData(13, 6),
        new SalesData(14, 18),
        new SalesData(15, 4),
        new SalesData(16, 8),
        new SalesData(17, 3),
        new SalesData(18, 12),
        new SalesData(19, 7),
        new SalesData(20, 3),
        new SalesData(21, 8),
        new SalesData(22, 12),
        new SalesData(23, 6),
        new SalesData(24, 18),
        new SalesData(25, 4),
        new SalesData(26, 8),
        new SalesData(27, 3),
        new SalesData(28, 12),
        new SalesData(29, 7),
        new SalesData(30, 3),
        new SalesData(31, 8),
        new SalesData(32, 12),
        new SalesData(33, 6),
        new SalesData(34, 18),
        new SalesData(35, 4),
        new SalesData(36, 8),
        new SalesData(37, 3),
        new SalesData(38, 12),
        new SalesData(39, 7),
        new SalesData(40, 3),
      ];
    
      _getSeriesData() {
        List<charts.Series<SalesData, int>> series = [
          charts.Series(
              //dot color is fillcolorfn
              fillColorFn: (SalesData series, _) =>
                  charts.MaterialPalette.green.shadeDefault,
              //seriesColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.red),
    
              id: "Sales",
              data: data,
              patternColorFn: (SalesData series, _) => charts.MaterialPalette.white,
              // areaColorFn: ((SalesData series, _) => charts.MaterialPalette.black),
              domainUpperBoundFn: (SalesData series, _) => series.domainUpper,
              domainLowerBoundFn: (SalesData series, _) => series.domainLower,
              measureUpperBoundFn: (SalesData series, _) => series.measureUpper,
              measureLowerBoundFn: (SalesData series, _) => series.measureLower,
              domainFn: (SalesData series, _) => series.year,
              measureFn: (SalesData series, _) => series.sales,
              colorFn: (SalesData series, _) =>
                  charts.MaterialPalette.red.shadeDefault),
        ];
    
        return series;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(800),
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(20),
                right: ScreenUtil().setWidth(20),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Text(
                  //   "Sales of a company over the years",
                  //   style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  // ),
                  // SizedBox(
                  //   height: 20,
                  // ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: ScreenUtil().setWidth(20),
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(50),
                        width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(100),
                        child: Text("hello"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
    
                  Expanded(
                    child: new charts.LineChart(
                      _getSeriesData(),
                      animate: true,
    
                      // domainAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                      //     // Set the initial viewport by providing a new AxisSpec with the
                      //     // desired viewport, in NumericExtents.
                      //     viewport: new charts.NumericExtents(0.0, 40.0)),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

my output image is below

[image: output image of above code]

Comment: can you please describe the problem in details?

Comment: I need a scrollable line chart in flutter can you  help

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the two images that you've shared and the only difference that I can see seems to only be different colors used on those charts. You can try using [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart) plugin to see if it fits your use case. With `fl_chart`, it allows you to modify the charts color as detailed on the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/fl_chart/latest/fl_chart/AxisChartData/backgroundColor.html).